# file_put_contents

Tags: php, json

Подскажите пожалуйста, есть код который записывает все orderid из цикла в текстовый файл.

```
$orders = [];
$file = 'bp.txt';
foreach ($array['orders'] as $order) {
$orders[] = $order['orderid'];
}
file_put_contents ($file, implode($orders));
```

Как сделать что бы этот orderid был в ссылки такого типа `<a href="orderid"></a>`

Спасибо.

Comment: в цикле `$orders[] = "<a href=\"{$order['orderid']}\"></a>"`;

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Это имеется ввиду?

```
$orders = [];
$file = 'bp.txt';
foreach ($array['orders'] as $order) {
    $orders[] = '<a href="' . $order['orderid'] . '"></a>' 
}
file_put_contents ($file, implode($orders));
```